# Why the directory layout is different between publish and publishLocal

Tags: sbt, publish

context : My artefact is a SBT plugin that I publish to my company Nexus repository.

Why the directory layout is different between publish (to a Nexus repository) and publishLocal :

**With publishLocal**

```
/Users/yamo/.ivy2/local/a.b.c/xxx/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/xxx.jar
```

**With publish**

```
http://mvnrepo/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/a/b/c/xxx_2.10_0.13/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/xxx-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Is there a way to see the pattern used with an `inspect` command ?

`inspect publishTo` only returns the url

I want to understand that because I can't use this dependency (unresolved) from another project when I publish to Nexus (and it works when I publish locally).

Answer (score 0):

`publishLocal` uses the ivy style to publish to local ivy2 repository.

`publish` uses the maven style to publish to Nexus.

It seems there is a convention to publish sbt plugins with the ivy style but I used the default as I publish to my company repo.

Anyway, I added a `Pattern` on the other project, and now the dependency is resolved.

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("nexus-snapshots", url("http://mvnrepo/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"))(Patterns(Resolver.mavenStyleBasePattern))
```

For an unknown reason, this doesn't work

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("nexus-snapshots", url("http://mvnrepo/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"))(Resolver.mavenStylePatterns)
```